# Table view Help…..selected cells from one table view passed to another table view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

[image]

This is a two part question...

1. My problem is....figuring out how to have the selected cells on the first table view...(which are `pfobjects` from parse) save into an array and then be able to populate those selected cells on another tableview controller....
2. How can you store the selected cells of the first table view into ONE table view cell on the other tableview and then have a disclosure indicator on it that opens up to see all the added cells? sorry this is more conceptual than concrete code to change or add to... here is what i have so far...
   thanks in advance friends.

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

       var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! PFTableViewCell!
       if cell == nil {
          cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
       }
       // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell

       if let customerFirstName = object?["customerName"] as? String {
          cell?.textLabel?.text = customerFirstName
       }

      if let customerStreetAddress = object?["customerStreetAddress"] as? String {
          cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = customerStreetAddress
      }

      if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() {
         for var i = 0; i < indexPaths.count; ++i {

            var thisPath = (indexPaths as! [NSIndexPath])[i]
            var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(thisPath)
            if let cell = cell {

              self.addedPoolarray.append(cell)
              // Do something with the cell
             // If it's a custom cell, downcast to the proper type
            }
      }
   }

   func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == "toRoutesVc" {
           let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! UITableViewController

       }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Remove these code:

```
if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() {
   for var i = 0; i < indexPaths.count; ++i {

      var thisPath = (indexPaths as! [NSIndexPath])[i]
      var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(thisPath)
      if let cell = cell {

        self.addedPoolarray.append(cell)
        // Do something with the cell
        // If it's a custom cell, downcast to the proper type
      }
}
```

It's incorrect. UITableView re-use cells that means one cell will be run again with a different `PFObject` and a different indexPath.

Instead, you can populate those selected cells on another tableview controller in the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toRoutesVc" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! RoutesVC

        let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()

        /* 
           If the first table view controller 
           and the another table view controller have the same data source, 
           simply pass the indexPaths 
        */
        // destination.selectedObjects = indexPaths

        /* Or pass the PFObjects: */
        var selectedObjects = [PFObject]()
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            selectedObjects.append(objects[indexPath.row])
        }
        destination.selectedObjects = selectedObjects
    }
}
```

You need to create a custom controller (subclass of `UITableViewController`) with an array property that received from the first table view.

```
class RoutesVC: UITableViewController {

    var selectedObjects: [AnyObject]?

    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write that out! appreciate it! just got home and ill give it a shot tomorrow  :)!!